# Do I need to terminate a thread if its detached?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a weird question that I can't find an answer to. Let's suppose I launch a thread that contains a `while(1)` (i.e. thread never returns) using `pthread_create(...)` but as soon as I create it I detach the thread. Later on, the object that initiated this thread is destroyed.

What happens to that thread? Is this a forever taken resource?

Answer (score 4):

Thread belongs to process. As soon as your process terminates, all threads within the process terminate as well. Destroying the object who initiated the thread doesn't affect running state of the thread. But if the thread has access to the destroyed object, you might encounter core dump problem.

Comment: On Windows, this depends on whether you use _ExitThread_ to terminate the main thread . So if you use _ExitThread_ to terminate the main thread, process will not terminate until all threads have terminated: [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/27/10054832.aspx)

Comment: @stamhaney Not sure what you are commenting, but when the process terminates (exit, _exit, _Exit) all its threads are terminated as well. You are right that the main thread can be terminated without terminating the process, but I am not sure how relevant this fact here.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin, my intent was in pointing out that the process will not terminate, if the main thread is terminated using _ExitThread_ and so the running threads in that process will not terminate, in such a condition. The comment is specific to Evans comment